# VS2015 stloc.0 and ldloc.0 are removed from compilation instructions

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, mono, visual-studio-2015

I am using Mono.Cecil.dll to decompile a VS 2015 app. 
During decompilation I noticed that there are 2 instructions (stloc.0 & ldloc.0) that are missing.
This did not happen when I decompiled a VS 2013 application.

Is there a problem with the decompiler or Visual Studio 2015 complier has changed?

Update:

I have decompiled the code using ILDasm. Here is what can be found in 2015 and 2013 in Initialize component. The problem still appears:

2015

```
.method private hidebysig instance void  InitializeComponent() cil managed
{
    // Code size       125 (0x7d)
    .maxstack  4
    IL_0000:  ldtoken    VS2015DotNet4test.Form1
    IL_0005:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_000a:  newobj     instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type)
    IL_000f:  ldarg.0
    IL_0010:  newobj     instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label::.ctor()
    IL_0015:  stfld      class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label VS2015DotNet4test.Form1::label1
    IL_001a:  ldarg.0
    IL_001b:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::SuspendLayout()
    IL_0020:  dup
    IL_0021:  ldarg.0
    IL_0022:  ldfld      class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label VS2015DotNet4test.Form1::label1
    IL_0027:  ldstr      "label1"
    IL_002c:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager::ApplyResources(object,
                                                                                                        string)
    IL_0031:  ldarg.0
    IL_0032:  ldfld      class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label VS2015DotNet4test.Form1::label1
    IL_0037:  ldstr      "label1"
    IL_003c:  callvirt   instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::set_Name(string)
    IL_0041:  ldarg.0
    IL_0042:  ldstr      "$this"
    IL_0047:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager::ApplyResources(object,
                                                                                                        string)
    IL_004c:  ldarg.0
    IL_004d:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_004e:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl::set_AutoScaleMode(valuetype [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode)
    IL_0053:  ldarg.0
    IL_0054:  call       instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control/ControlCollection [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::get_Controls()
    IL_0059:  ldarg.0
    IL_005a:  ldfld      class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label VS2015DotNet4test.Form1::label1
    IL_005f:  callvirt   instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control/ControlCollection::Add(class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control)
    IL_0064:  ldarg.0
    IL_0065:  ldstr      "Form1"
    IL_006a:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::set_Name(string)
    IL_006f:  ldarg.0
    IL_0070:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0071:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::ResumeLayout(bool)
    IL_0076:  ldarg.0
    IL_0077:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::PerformLayout()
    IL_007c:  ret
} // end of method Form1::InitializeComponent
```

2013

```
.method private hidebysig instance void  InitializeComponent() cil managed
{
  // Code size       127 (0x7f)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init (class [System]System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldtoken    VS2013DotNet4test.Form1
  IL_0005:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_000a:  newobj     instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type)
  IL_000f:  stloc.0
  IL_0010:  ldarg.0
  IL_0011:  newobj     instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label::.ctor()
  IL_0016:  stfld      class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label VS2013DotNet4test.Form1::label1
  IL_001b:  ldarg.0
  IL_001c:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::SuspendLayout()
  IL_0021:  ldloc.0
  IL_0022:  ldarg.0
  IL_0023:  ldfld      class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label VS2013DotNet4test.Form1::label1
  IL_0028:  ldstr      "label1"
  IL_002d:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager::ApplyResources(object,
                                                                                                        string)
  IL_0032:  ldarg.0
  IL_0033:  ldfld      class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label VS2013DotNet4test.Form1::label1
  IL_0038:  ldstr      "label1"
  IL_003d:  callvirt   instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::set_Name(string)
  IL_0042:  ldloc.0
  IL_0043:  ldarg.0
  IL_0044:  ldstr      "$this"
  IL_0049:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager::ApplyResources(object,
                                                                                                        string)
  IL_004e:  ldarg.0
  IL_004f:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0050:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl::set_AutoScaleMode(valuetype [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode)
  IL_0055:  ldarg.0
  IL_0056:  call       instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control/ControlCollection [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::get_Controls()
  IL_005b:  ldarg.0
  IL_005c:  ldfld      class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label VS2013DotNet4test.Form1::label1
  IL_0061:  callvirt   instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control/ControlCollection::Add(class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control)
  IL_0066:  ldarg.0
  IL_0067:  ldstr      "Form1"
  IL_006c:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::set_Name(string)
  IL_0071:  ldarg.0
  IL_0072:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0073:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::ResumeLayout(bool)
  IL_0078:  ldarg.0
  IL_0079:  call       instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::PerformLayout()
  IL_007e:  ret
} // end of method Form1::InitializeComponent
```

Comment: Any chance you could copy the code out as text and paste instead?

Comment: There's also no need for this much code, I suspect. It would be good to show: a) the C#; b) the IL generated by VS2013; c) the IL generated by 2015. Also note the options you're using (debug or release build for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, this shouldn't make any observable difference - it's likely simply the result of Roslyn being a smarter compiler. The value is still on the virtual stack, ready to be used when needed. There's no need to store it in a (virtual) local.

The VS2015 compiler is completely new, built from scratch, so some differences are to be expected.

Note how the VS2013 version has `.maxstack` of 3, compared to 4 in VS2015 - this is the reason. VS2013's compiler simply saved one stack slot, while VS2015 saved one local slot (and a few instructions).

The value is used twice in the code, each of the compilations dealing with that in a different way: VS2013 saved the value in a local, to be retrieved when needed. VS2015 simply let the value stay on stack, and just before it's used for the first time, `dup`ped it.

It might be interesting to have a look at the resulting x86 assembly from the JIT compilation - the two might even produce identical code, since most of the optimizations happen on the JIT level, not the C# compilation itself.

**EDIT:**

Okay, let's have a closer look at the virtual stack in the VS2015 code (I'm simplifying for clarity):

- Push `Form` as a `RuntimeHandle`, pop it and push the `Type` (== `typeof(Form)`)
- Pop `Type`, push `new ResourceManager` (takes the `Type` argument)
- Push `this`, push `new Label`, pop both to store the label in the field `this.label1`
- **Current stack:** just the `ResourceManager`
- Push `this` again, and use it to call `Control.SuspendLayout` (== `this.SuspendLayout`)
- `dup` the last value on stack (the `ResourceManager` instance)
- Push `this`, push `this.label1` (popping `this`), push `"label1"`
- **Current stack:** `ResourceManager`, `ResourceManager`, `this.label1`, `"label1"`
- Call `ApplyResources` (which takes three arguments, so pop the last three)

After all this, we still have the `ResourceManager` on stack, without using any local.

Comment: The thing is that I need to parse the instruction list in order to get the resources from it and this means that I have to find out somehow what modifications were made.

Comment: @Mihai Well, that has nothing to do with the locals, does it? Is there something in the new code that disrupts your analysis? Did you assume that the resource manager *must* be assigned to a local?

Comment: Based on the IL instructions I am creating a “stack” of block statements, which is from what I understood the virtual stack you were talking about. The thing is that in VS2013 ldloc.0 pushed a local variable on stack based on the ComponentResourceManager  V_0 initialization but dup duplicates the last value on stack which is an instruction SuspendLayout()in my case. 
Is there only one stack we are talking about or the values are also stored elsewhere? Where does dup retrieve the value from?
Without optimizing the code, it works. The code generated is the same as in 2013 with ldloc and stloc.

Comment: @Mihai I think your approach only works by accident, really. Locals are a simple ordered array, and `dup` duplicates the last value on stack - which *isn't* `SuspendLayout`, since `SuspendLayout` doesn't return a value. The virtual stack only contains values/references, not return addresses or anything. To interpret it correctly, you need to know the input and output parameters of every method call - once you have that, it's pretty trivial to implement. Go instruction by instruction, and you'll see it's the resource manager that's actually `dup`ped.

Comment: @Mihai I've editted in a view at what happens on the virtual stack. Perhaps that will make it a bit clearer what you're thinking wrong here.

Comment: Thank you, the explanation provided made me understand the how the instructions are rendered. The custom stack i am creating is not a virtual stack, The changes are pretty complex but now I now where to start.